# Composer.phar Install error Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

When ever I try to run a php composer.phar install command in ssh I get the same error, don't know why this is happing?

**Output** : http://pastebin.com/zpnKkubM

> Warning: This development build of composer is over 30 days old. It is
>   recommended to update it by running "compos  er.phar self-update" to
>   get the latest version. Loading composer repositories with package
>   information Installing dependencies from lock file Generating autoload
>   files Updating the "app/config/parameters.yml" file
>
> ```
> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]   Warning: constant(): Couldn't find constant Monolog\Logger::DEBUG in
> ```
>
> C:\Use
>   rs\brent.french\Documents\www\clients\app.malltomobile.co.uk\public\vendor\
>   symfony\monolog-bundle\Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\DependencyInjection\Mon
>   ologExtension.php line 36
>
> ```
> Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache
> ```
>
> handling the post-install-cmd event ter  minated with an exception
>
> ```
> [RuntimeException]   An error occurred when executing the ""cache:clear --no-warmup"" command.
>
> install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [  --no-progress]
> ```
>
> [-v|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader]

Comment: You might want to update your composer first. Secondly, what version of monolog are you using? You can check with "./composer.phar show <vendor>/<package>"

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your composer just run   **php composer.phar update**

for more go [here.](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#update)